# Integrating Paypal using asp.net and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, integration

Good Morning...

Actually i wanted to Learn how to integrate paypal into asp.net, suppose i have a online trainning center and students have to register, so i need paypal for money transaction. So can anyone teach me how to do they, step by step.

I have already gone through gooogle and has already break my head, but none of they are not helpful for me. Can any one teach me, what is paypal and whats the use in dotnet integration in detail i.e., from creating a sandbox account to completing the paypal transaction and coming back to online training website.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the [Express Checkout APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/), which consist of [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_SOAP/), [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_SOAP/), and [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_SOAP/).

PayPal provides a [.NET SDK](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-dotnet) to make this easy for you, or you could simply build the API request strings and parse the responses yourself based on the API reference links I provided above.

Comment: What if i create a new button from paypal website and pay it in my code.... Is it a good practice???

Answer (score 0):

Along with Andrew's suggestion of using the Express Checkout APIs, I'd also suggest taking a look at [PayPal's REST APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/) for making payments.  For new integrations, PayPal recommends using the REST APIs as they are what PayPal will be building upon and improving in the future.  An SDK is available both on [GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK) and [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPal) that provides quick and easy access to the various REST APIs.

There's also a [sample project](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/tree/master/Samples) on GitHub that shows you how to use the SDK as well as a [wiki](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki) with more helpful information on how to get started using the SDK.

The Express Checkout APIs (part of PayPal's Classic APIs), while entrenched and still widely used, will not be updated with newer features brought to the REST services (e.g. webhooks).

Comment: To my knowledge webhooks are the same as IPN, no..??  If you look at the API version history you'll see they are actually still adding more features to Classic which is going to make it tough for them to ever catch up with REST.  Classic is much more mature right now. REST has too many limitations for me to recommend it at this point.

Comment: @AndrewAngell yes, there are a few features that are still being added to Classic, but the PayPal engineering teams are currently putting their focus behind the REST services.  Currenlty, most of the REST services simply wrap the Classic services (sometimes badly, in the case of the Invoicing API...).  But for simple payments, REST is mostly at parity with Classic.  Webhooks are similar to IPN but are 1) much more secure and 2) much more reliable than IPN.  However, your point about Classic being much more mature is definitely valid. :)

Comment: I'm interested in more detail about it being more secure and reliable..??  I have never had any such issues with IPN.  They're both just HTTP POST data, right?  How are webhooks more secure?  What reliability issues have you had with IPN?  I've been using it for years without any issues at all, so I'm just curious.

Comment: The metadata included with Webhooks allow for better verification of the received event and doesn't require the client to post back to PayPal.  IPN also allows you to declare an HTTP endpoint, whereas Webhooks require an HTTPS endpoint.  Regarding reliability, the Webhooks service is supported by a much newer and more robust backend.  IPN is built on an older technology stack and while you may have not had any issues, it has historically had its fair share of problems when attempting to send out certain notifications.

Comment: I should also mention that Webhook validation support is coming very soon in the PayPal .NET SDK (and is outlined [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/#event-security) on the PayPal Developer site).  The PayPal SDK team is just waiting on the Webhooks team to provide us with a final cert to include with the SDK that will be used when performing the validation.

Comment: Ok, cool.  Thanks for the details.  I'll have to look more into that.  Do you know if they work with all transaction types, or do webhooks only work with REST transactions?

Comment: No problem! Webhooks only work with REST transactions (it's mentioned on the [Webhooks overview](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/#definitions) page as a note in the **Event types** section): "Calls to Classic APIs will only generate IPNs, and not Webhook events."

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
  <form target="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="admin@test.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="D-T purchase"   />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="500.00" />
    <input  type="submit" value="Buy!" />
  </form>
</body>
```